# sensor payload hex to text node red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I would love to have some input from somebody that knows how to explain how to create a hex to "text" decoder in node red.

I have an Elsys sensor that produces a payload hex with temperature, humidity and so on.

Payload that is delivered is "0100df02170400dc0500070e13", on their website website they have a simple decoder that works great but I would like to create a nodechain which decodes the data as it being delivered, and parse it to an influxdb.

https://www.elsys.se/en/elsys-payload/ is the link to the payload JavaScript.

anyone that have done something like this before? I have searched for hours on internet for some kind of example but found nothing, or I'm just looking for the wrong thing.

[image: Here is my setup]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided gives the JavaScript required to decode that payload.

You could use that code in a Function node in order to do the decoding within a flow.

For example, an Inject node configured to inject the payload `0100df02170400dc0500070e13`, passing through this Function results in a payload of:

```
{"temperature":223,"humidity":23,"light":220,"motion":0,"vdd":3603}
```

---

```
/*
  ______ _       _______     _______ 
 |  ____| |     / ____\ \   / / ____|
 | |__  | |    | (___  \ \_/ / (___  
 |  __| | |     \___ \  \   / \___ \ 
 | |____| |____ ____) |  | |  ____) |
 |______|______|_____/   |_| |_____/ 

  ELSYS simple payload decoder. 
  Use it as it is or remove the bugs :)
  www.elsys.se
  peter@elsys.se
*/
const TYPE_TEMP     =0x01; //temp 2 bytes -3276.8°C -->3276.7°C
const TYPE_RH       =0x02; //Humidity 1 byte  0-100%
const TYPE_ACC      =0x03; //acceleration 3 bytes X,Y,Z -128 --> 127 +/-63=1G
const TYPE_LIGHT    =0x04; //Light 2 bytes 0-->65535 Lux
const TYPE_MOTION   =0x05; //No of motion 1 byte  0-255
const TYPE_CO2      =0x06; //Co2 2 bytes 0-65535 ppm 
const TYPE_VDD      =0x07; //VDD 2byte 0-65535mV
const TYPE_ANALOG1  =0x08; //VDD 2byte 0-65535mV
const TYPE_GPS      =0x09; //3bytes lat 3bytes long binary
const TYPE_PULSE1   =0x0A; //2bytes relative pulse count

function bin16dec(bin) {
    var num=bin&0xFFFF;
    if (0x8000 & num)
        num = - (0x010000 - num);
    return num;
}
function bin8dec(bin) {
    var num=bin&0xFF;
    if (0x80 & num) 
        num = - (0x0100 - num);
    return num;
}
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
    return bytes;
}

function DecodeElsysPayload(data){
    var obj ={};
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        switch(data[i]){
            case TYPE_TEMP: //Temperature
                var temp=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                temp=bin16dec(temp);
                obj.temperature=temp;
                i+=2;
            break;
            case TYPE_RH: //Humidity
                var rh=(data[i+1]);
                obj.humidity=rh;
                i+=1;
            break;
            case TYPE_ACC: //Acceleration
                obj.x=bin8dec(data[i+1]);
                obj.y=bin8dec(data[i+2]);
                obj.z=bin8dec(data[i+3]);
                i+=3;
            break;
            case TYPE_LIGHT: //Light
                var light=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                obj.light=light;
                i+=2;
            break;
            case TYPE_MOTION: //Motion sensor(PIR)
                var motion=(data[i+1]);
                obj.motion=motion;
                i+=1;
            break;
            case TYPE_CO2: //CO2
                var co2=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                obj.co2=co2;
                i+=2;
            break;
            case TYPE_VDD: //Battery level
                var vdd=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                obj.vdd=vdd;
                i+=2;
            break;
            case TYPE_ANALOG1: //Analog input 1
                var analog1=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                obj.analog1=analog1;
                i+=2;
            break;
            case TYPE_GPS: //gps
                obj.lat=(data[i+1]<<16)|(data[i+2]<<8)|(data[i+3]);
                obj.long=(data[i+4]<<16)|(data[i+5]<<8)|(data[i+6]);
                i+=6;
            break;
            case TYPE_PULSE1: //Pulse input 1
                var pulse1=(data[i+1]<<8)|(data[i+2]);
                obj.pulse1=pulse1;
                i+=2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

msg.payload = DecodeElsysPayload(hexToBytes(msg.payload));
return msg;
```

Comment: i tryed just to add the code into a function node and got the answer 2018-03-14 10:25:37node: 70a90f48.0918f
msg.payload : Object
{ empty } so for sure i must be doing something wrong.?

Comment: Have updated my answer showing that injecting the payload you have to that function results in the expected object - so the function does work. How are you passing in your data?

Comment: Ok i see that it work when i add an inject node. but how do i move the data from an function node to the next one so i can decode the data? I edited my question with a picture of my setup pretty simple one

Comment: It would help if you described the flow you want this to be part of. It looks like you are receiving an HTTP request with the data in. What message property is the data in? Use the Debug sidebar to understand the structure of your incoming data. Identify the path to the hex string you want to decode, and replace the msg.payload reference in the Function I provided to match.